# Accessing an object with stored values for css background image, based on td element .text() value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have checked other answers but found nothing alike. I am not sure my approach is feasible.

I have a CRUD app, all the PHP and SQL code works fine.
On user input it gets food values for the queried food.

The foods name is placed in a td element.

What I want is to add a background image based on the jQuery value of that td elements .text() method.

This is the HTML, it's all generated server side:

```
             <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Food Name</th>
                <th>Calories/100g</th>
                <th>Proteins</th>
                <th>Carbohydrates</th>
                <th>Fats</th>
                <th>Time_to_burn_by_running</th>
            </tr>
```

I get the current value of the td element like this:

```
var currentFood = $('td:eq( 1 )').text(); //cache it
alert(currentFood); // test it, works fine
```

I store the background images in this object:

```
var imgSources = { 

almond: "https://www.vigon.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/almonds.jpg",
banana: "https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Banana3-
1020x765.jpg", 
cereal: "http://nutryvidasaude.com.br/Imagens/Produtos/240420170917331.jpg",

 };
```

Now, I could obviously do an if evaluation for every food choice and hard code that in a function, but that is no good and against every DRY principle out there.

Here is what I try instead, I am not sure if it's ok to concatenate things like this.

```
$(function(){
if(jQuery){
/* alert("i am here"); */
}

if($('table').length == 0) {
alert("table is not generated yet");
}
else {
$('table').prop('id', 'mainTable');
var reso = $('#mainTable').attr('id')

alert("table id is "+ reso);

// this is the relevant part
var currentFood = $('td:eq( 1 )').text();
alert(currentFood); 
alert(imgSources.cereal); // testing what is returned.
 if($('table').length > 0) { $('#mainTable').fadeOut(100, function() {
$('#mainTable').fadeIn(2000);

// this one does not work
$('#mainTable').css('background-image', 'imgSources + "." + 
currentFood').fadeIn(3000);
});} 


}
});
```

No error message in the console. Is this just a concatenation issue? 
If i do :

```
$('#mainTable').css('background-image', 'someurl').fadeIn(3000);
```

Then it works.

I am running this on a server, I hope this is good enough without a fiddle/codepen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `imgSources` is a variable, so you cannot include it in the string - you need to concatenate it, along with the property you're trying to access.

You'll also need to use bracket notation to access the object as you have stored the property name in the `currentFood` variable. Try this:

```js
var imgSources = {
  almond: "https://www.vigon.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/almonds.jpg",
  banana: "https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Banana3-1020x765.jpg", 
  cereal: "http://nutryvidasaude.com.br/Imagens/Produtos/240420170917331.jpg",
};

var currentFood = $('#mainTable td:eq(1)').text();
$('#mainTable').css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSources[currentFood] + ')').fadeIn(3000)
```

```css
#mainTable {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mainTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Food Name</th>
      <th>Calories/100g</th>
      <th>Proteins</th>
      <th>Carbohydrates</th>
      <th>Fats</th>
      <th>Time_to_burn_by_running</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>almond</td>
      <td>550</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>55 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Tried, does not work either. The background is not appplied if I check dev tools.
Could it be that the css method must take a string, even if that string contains variables?

Comment: No, so long as the end result provided to the function is a string of valid format, it will work. There must be another issue in your code. It would help a lot to see the HTML that goes with this - even if you just copy it from the 'view source' window after it's been generated

Comment: Just tried to pass it as a string, no luck.
View source generates this:
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 31px black;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

Comment: That's the CSS, not the HTML

Comment: Sorry
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Food Name</th>
     <th>Calories/100g</th>
     <th>Proteins</th>
     <th>Carbohydrates</th>
     <th>Fats</th>
     <th>Time_to_burn_by_running</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>almond</td>
    <td>550</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>48</td>
    <td>55 </td>
   </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>

Comment: Your code seems to be working - note that you need to ensure that the table is high enough to show the image content. I added a working example to the answer.]

Comment: Would not this > background-size: 100% 100%; make sure all fits?

Comment: Oh my, it seems it was the url part in the second css method parameter, phew. Thank you very much, this is a breakthrough, my first full stack app done and finished:-)

Comment: Well, you gave it the finishing touch:-)
Just one more thing, I have tried this format with the dot access notation, does not work. But why do I have to access the object with bracket notation?

Comment: It's because `currentFood` is a variable that holds the name of the property - it is not the name of the property directly. Eg if you had `var imgSources = { currentFood: 'img.jpg' }` then it would work.